# Formatting Mysql TimeStamp Jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql

I'm trying to format a mysql TIMESTAMP I get using the get.json function in jquery to look like this Nov 21st 2010, tried formatting through the initial select from the php script using the DATE_FORMAT class but it is all the information is read out as undefined. I tested out the php script by itself and it worked fine.

php script, trying to format the TIMESTAMP

```
$mangaInfo = "SELECT manga.mangaName,chapter.chapterNumber,chapter.chapterName,chapter.chapterID, DATE_FORMAT(chapter.dateUploaded,'%b %D %Y') FROM manga INNER JOIN chapter ON manga.mangaID=chapter.mangaID ORDER BY chapter.dateUploaded DESC LIMIT 10";
```

Jquery script which is trying to process the date

```
$.getJSON('/chaptersRetrival.php', function(data) 
        {
                    $.each(data, function(index, array) {
                    $("<a/>").attr({
                    href: 'http://www.neuromanga.com/mangaReader.php?chapterNo='+this['chapterID']+'&#pageNo=1',
                    title: this['mangaName']+ " " + this['chapterNumber'] +" "+ this['chapterName'] + " "
                    }).html(array.mangaName+" "+ array.chapterNumber +" "+ array.chapterName + " " + array.dateUploaded + " "+"<br />").appendTo("#mangaChapters");
                });
            });
       };
```

Comment: Please show some of the code that doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your problem:

`DATE_FORMAT(chapter.dateUploaded,'%b %D %Y')`

You need to actually define it AS:

`DATE_FORMAT(chapter.dateUploaded,'%b %D %Y') as dateUploaded`

You are calling `array.dateUploaded` but none is defined in your JS result.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple in php

```
date('M jS Y',strtotime($mysql_timestamp));
```

Comment: how does this apply to the question? He is converting timestamp with `DATE_FORMAT()`

Comment: there was no code example provided before, and I'm showing how he can convert any date string to desired one.